# Processing email from outlook 7bit encoding causes funny characters in output

Tags: c#, email, smtp, 7-bit

I am working on a project where I am building my own SMTP server. (please nobody ask why or provide me with things like Postfix, I have my reasons).

It is mostly working fine except with Outlook there seems to be some problem with encoding of the data that I am encoding from Outlook.

I keep getting content as follows:

```
<html xmlns:v=3D"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" =
xmlns:o=3D"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" =
xmlns:w=3D"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" =
```

Instead of:

```
<html xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" =
xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" =
xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" =
```

Notice the 3D isn't there on the valid content.

I have a function that listens to the socket for SMTP data which looks like the following:

```
if (stream.CanRead)
                {

                    byte[] serverData = new byte[1024];
                    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                    int numberOfBytesRead = 0;
                    do
                    {
                        numberOfBytesRead = stream.Read(serverData, 0, serverData.Length);
                        Encoding encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("UTF-7", new FallbackEncoding(), new FallbackDecoding());
                        stringBuilder.AppendFormat("{0}", encoding.GetString(serverData, 0, numberOfBytesRead));
                    } while (stream.DataAvailable);

                    return stringBuilder.ToString();
```

In my FallbackDecoding function I have the following code

```
class FallbackDecoding : DecoderFallback
    {
        public override int MaxCharCount
        {
            get
            {
                return 1;
            }
        }

        public override DecoderFallbackBuffer CreateFallbackBuffer()
        {
            return new Buffer();
        }

        private class Buffer : DecoderFallbackBuffer
        {
            private int _fallbackIndex;
            private string _fallbackString;

            public override int Remaining
            {
                get
                {
                    return _fallbackString.Length - _fallbackIndex;
                }
            }

            public override bool Fallback(byte[] bytesUnknown, int index)
            {
                byte unknownChar = bytesUnknown[index];
                _fallbackString = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(new[] { (byte)(unknownChar & 127) });
                _fallbackIndex = 0;
                return true;
            }

            public override char GetNextChar()
            {
                if (Remaining > 0)
                {
                    return _fallbackString[_fallbackIndex++];
                }
                else
                {
                    return '\0';
                }
            }

            public override bool MovePrevious()
            {
                if (_fallbackIndex > 0)
                {
                    _fallbackIndex--;
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        }
```

For some reason the decoder fall back class is throwing an exception in the function `public override bool Fallback`. It throws an exception because `bytesunknown` only has 1 item in the array, but the `index` parameter is 128 so its throwing an index out of range exception but I have no idea why.

I've tried changing ASCII to UTF-7 as Outlook sends the data in 7bit but it doesn't seem to make any difference.

Due to the HTML in the email I'm receiving, when I pass the email in, the formatting is wrong and sometimes I'll just get garbage in the email.

### Update

Full email headers as requested

```
Message-ID: <000d01d0dc52$0c0d4690$2427d3b0$@chrisboard.co.uk>
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
    boundary="----=_NextPart_000_000E_01D0DC5A.6DD24AD0"
X-Mailer: Microsoft Outlook 15.0
Thread-Index: AdDcUeHbbPyOUTipQ462DEYroR+DWg==
Content-Language: en-gb

This is a multipart message in MIME format.

------=_NextPart_000_000E_01D0DC5A.6DD24AD0
Content-Type: text/plain;
    charset="us-ascii"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

This is the content of the message


------=_NextPart_000_000E_01D0DC5A.6DD24AD0
Content-Type: text/html;
    charset="us-ascii"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

<html xmlns:v=3D"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" =
xmlns:o=3D"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" =
xmlns:w=3D"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" =
xmlns:m=3D"http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2004/12/omml" =
xmlns=3D"http://www.w3.o
```

Comment: Could you post `MIME*:` and `Content*` headers of the message?  The message looks like encoded with `quoted-printable` (`=` at line ends), it does not seem like plain `7bit`.

Comment: @AndrzejA.Filip I've added the extra information, I do see that some of it is 7-bit but the HTML is quoted printable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Quoted-printable and ASCII text with long lines and `=`

The html attachment is encoded using [quoted-printable encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quoted-printable). Quoted-printable uses special 3 bytes sequences starting with `=`. Quoted printable encodes `=` as `=3D`. It is the only printable ascii character (33-126) that must be encoded.

BTW `=` at end of line is also product of `quoted-printable` encoding.  It "breaks" long lines.

Comment: Thanks, I missed that, I didn't realise there could be multiple content transfer encoding headers.